# Email notification for Office 365 in jenkins ios build fails

Tags: ios, iphone, email, jenkins, continuous-integration

When I try to build an iOS App with Jenkins , I got the error in Email notification for Office365 but for gmail I am able to get notification.

**Error message:**
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP server you have configured in Jenkins probably allows you to send email within your organisation, but not outside of it (e.g. to Gmail) , unless you authenticate to the server first.

Check your SMTP configuration under Manage Jenkins > Configure System > E-mail Notification > Advanced.

Enable the "Use SMTP Authentication" checkbox and ensure that you have a valid username and password entered.

Comment: Hi I am able to get notification to gmail , when  i try to notify for Office 365 mail I am getting the error .